# How to dynamically calculate rowspan in a multi-level table from a nested JSON array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, html-table

I have a nested JSON array representing a multi-level table structure, and I'm trying to dynamically calculate the rowspan for each cell. Here's an example of my input data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "goal1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Objective1",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "50$" },
                    { "name": "80$" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Objective2",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "180$" },
                    { "name": "280$" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Objective1",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "380$" },
                    { "name": "280$" },
                    { "name": "480$" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm looking for a JavaScript solution to transform this array into a structure that includes rowspan values for each cell, like the following:

```
      [
    [
        {
            "name": "goal1",
            "rowspan": 7
        },
        {
            "name": "Objective1",
            "rowspan": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "50$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "80$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Objective2",
            "rowspan": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "180$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "280$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Objective1",
            "rowspan": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "380$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "280$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "480$",
            "rowspan": 1
        }
    ]
]
```

Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this dynamically in JavaScript?

this is what i tried

```
function calculateRowspan(data) {
    let result = [];
    let rowspanCount = 0;

    function processNode(node) {
        if (!node.children || node.children.length === 0) {
            return [{ name: node.name, rowspan: rowspanCount }];
        }

        let currentRow = [{ name: node.name, rowspan: 0 }];
        rowspanCount = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            const childResult = processNode(node.children[i]);
            rowspanCount += childResult.length;
            currentRow = currentRow.concat(childResult);
        }

        currentRow[0].rowspan = rowspanCount;
        return currentRow;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const goalResult = processNode(data[i]);
        result = result.concat(goalResult);
    }

    return result;
}

const inputArray = [
    {
        "name": "goal1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Objective1",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "50$" },
                    { "name": "80$" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Objective2",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "180$" },
                    { "name": "280$" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Objective1",
                "children": [
                    { "name": "380$" },
                    { "name": "280$" },
                    { "name": "480$" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show any research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. It would seem as though you could do a simple for loop and set `rowspan` to the length of the `children` below it but I'm not clear on how the structure you're returning maps to the table construction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested for-loops and set the rowspan accordingly. With this approach you will add each object into one array. If you would like to add nested array you could just wrap those before pushing it in the result array.

```js
function calculateRowspan(data) {
  let result = [];

  for (let item of data) {
    const rootRowSpan = item.children
      .map((child) => child.children.length)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    result.push({ name: item.name, rowspan: rootRowSpan });

    for (let childLevel1 of item.children) {
      result.push({
        name: childLevel1.name,
        rowspan: childLevel1.children.length,
      });

      for (let childLevel2 of childLevel1.children) {
        result.push({ name: childLevel2.name, rowspan: 1 });
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not able to form the table with this response it is slightly different it's flattening in to single array but i need as array of array object as asked in the question is that possible.

Comment: Alright. Yes this should be possible. But I am not sure if i understand the logic of wrapping the arrays as described in your question. You need the top-level array with the first childrens, then all the other second level children in another array? Is that right?